# GraphQL query fragment missing connection

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, relayjs

This React/Relay/GraphQL app has a simple container `App` and one nested index page `EntriesPage`. The `App` requests the `viewer`'s `id`, while the `EntriesPage` requests additional `viewer` fields like `name` and a list of `entries`.

The `EntriesPage` query fragment being sent to GraphQL correctly contains the additional `name` field but is missing the `entries` connection.

Any idea why `entries`, specified in the fragment, is being ignored, while `name` is happily included?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/891448/queries.png

Running a similar query in `GraphiQL` returns proper results.

Routes:

```js
export default (
  <Route
    path="/"
    component={App}
    queries={ViewerQueries}
  >
    <IndexRoute
      component={EntriesPage}
      queries={ViewerQueries}
    />
  </Route>
);
```

App.js

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id
      }
    `
  },
});
```

EntriesPage:

```js
class EntriesPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { viewer } = this.props;
    const entries = viewer.entries.edges.map(e => e.node);
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-3">
          <EntryList entries={entries} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-9">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(EntriesPage, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id,
        name,
        entries(first:10) {
          edges {node {id}}
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
```

Comment: Having pored over your example for a few minutes now, I'm stumped. Can you tell what's different between your app and the example in https://github.com/facebook/relay/tree/master/examples/todo. Why is your `entries` connection not fetched, and our `todos` connection is?

Comment: Also, can you inspect your compiled JS code and look to see that the `isConnection` metadata is being printed into the `viewer` query of `EntriesPage` for the `entries` connection field?